# Why? Class showing in Unit test coverage Even though not added in test targets

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest, test-coverage

I have a few UIView class which is coming under coverage even though. I haven't added them under unit test target. Neither in unit test nor UI unit test. but still those file showing.

I do not know whether they are included in test coverage.

Q: How we can remove them from unit test coverage?
Q: Are they involve in unit test coverage score?

Class included in unit test coverage:

[image]

Classes not added in test targets:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi [@Sandy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875943/sandy), to answer your questions:

> How we can remove them from unit test coverage?

As of Xcode 10.2 there is no way to exclude files from the test coverage report.

> Are they involve in unit test coverage score?

Yes they are. All the files contribute to the total coverage %.

If you want to compute a test coverage score that doesn't take into account certain files, your best chance is to write a script to parse the [`xccov`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018-403/?time=260) output.

I can't find any official documentation of how to interact with it but [this post](https://medium.com/xcblog/xccov-xcode-code-coverage-report-for-humans-466a4865aa18) is a good place to start.

Comment: xcov used to exclude coverage for ignore files. is this issue with latest xcov?

Answer (score 3):

I think that your problem is related with gather code coverage for all targets.

1. create new target - You can duplicate existing one.

[image]

2. Change **Host Application** to brand new target.

[image]

3. Change your test scheme settings to new target as source of code coverage. Please have a look at screenshots:

[image: Manage Schemes]

[image: Edit]

[image: Choose Gather coverage for...]

[image]

[image]

4. Remember add to your test file `@testable import UnitTestExampleCodeCoverage`
5. Add to new target files which you want. 
   In my example proj i have: `AppDelegate`, `ViewController`, `ViewController2`, `ViewController3`, `ViewController4`, `View`, `View2`, `View3`, `View4`. I added to new target: `AppDelegate`, `ViewController3`, `ViewController4`, `View3`, `View4` so only this five classes should be base to calculate code coverage.
6. Add tests to your classes.
7. **Code coverage report contain only classes added to new target**. Please remember that old target can be your main target - the new one is only kind of abstract layer to achieve your goal: "remove some classes from code coverage report".

[image]

Here is whole project: https://github.com/mStaruchowicz/SO55723759

Happy testing ;)

Comment: Yeah still If I am selecting the project target only, still those UIView files are added in the test.

Comment: That's true, but you can manage your targets e.g. add one more to keep only classes to tests and based on calculate code coverage.

Comment: but that will not give a clear report as those are specifics to files not to project target. isn't?

Comment: Why not clear?  Your goal is have a code coverage for your project excluded some `UIView` based on classes, right? So, you can create new target which will be contains only classes to calculate code coverage. Then you just set proper target for Code coverage as screen shot show.

Comment: @Sandy I added more informations how to achieve your goal. Hope that for now is everything clear :)

Comment: Screenshots contain misspelling. Should be `(...)Coverage` instead of `(...)Coveradge`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Nice one, @Mateusz! very detailed :)

Answer (score 1):

When you active coverage in your project, all files from the target will compute the coverage.

I recommend for you to use XCOV:
https://github.com/nakiostudio/xcov

You can run the coverage and put your ignored files to improve a correct coverage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want customizable UT coverage report where you can ignore the files you wish, [Slather](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather) can be a best tool.

you can ignore the files from coverage calculation by configuring the files in `.slather.yml` file under `ignore` option.

Please find the details [here](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather/issues/195) how to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

When unit tests run,

- Your app is launched
- Tests are injected and run

The problem is the app launch fires up your normal sequence, creating views and maybe initiating some network calls. This not only interferes with code coverage reporting — it potentially poisons your unit tests. For example, if you test notifications by having a unit test fire off a notification, you need to know that the only objects listening for that notification were created by the test, not lying around from app launch.

Another problem with ignoring coverage of certain files is: How are you going to see what your unit test coverage is of those files?

The solution is to use a different app delegate for testing that does almost nothing.